# Visualforce Private vs Public Getter/Setter Syntax/Structure & Order of Execution

Tags: apex, visualforce, order-of-execution, getter

There are already many threads on the confusion with Visualforce's [Lifecycle/Execution Order](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm), as their should be because its pretty confusing the more complicated your applications becomes. With that said, I assure you I've read many threads, articles, and SF documentation to prior to this post but I still have a question.

Understanding that a controller/extension's constructor executes before the getters, I had a situation where that didn't seem to be the case but I believe it is because of a misunderstanding about syntax.

If I setup a `get;set;` like this:

```
public List<Object__c> dropdown_list { get; set; } {
    // I thought this was setting up the getter 
    // but if I add a debug here it fires BEFORE
    // the constructor
}
```

But if I swap the syntax to the following:

```
public List<Object__c> dropdown_list { 
    get{
        // Now the execution order fires as expectedhow 
        // AFTER the constructor
    } set; 
}
```

Why is this? What am I not understanding about this and what is the proper terminology for the two structures (as well as any other unlisted scenarios)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening is that you are actually using an `Initialization Block`. See [Static and Instance Methods, Variables, and Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm) (Using Initialization Code).

> **Using Initialization Code**
>
> Instance initialization code is a block of code in the following form that is defined in a class.
>
> ```
> {
>     //code body
> }
> ```
>
> The instance initialization code in a class is executed each time an object is instantiated from that class. **These code blocks run before the constructor**.

*This block has nothing to do with your* `getter` *or* `setter`*, but is completely separate.*

---

If you use more conventional whitespace, it might be easier to see what is happening:

```
public List<Object__c> property { get; set; }

{
    // initialization block
    // this is the same syntax you use
}
```

Comment: I personally dislike this syntax-- that's what constructors are for. But, it's part of the language, and I will admit to abusing this feature from time to time, but it really goes against the entire OOP concept that Apex Code is trying to present.

Comment: I too find it distasteful. I've never found reason to use them myself.